# How to rotate and set origin by using command line

Tags: python, mesh, 3d-cursor

I tried to perform a batch operation by using blender CLI.
I want to rotate a mesh by X axis with -90d, and then place the mesh to world origin,
the operation I performed in the GUI is:

1. press keys: <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, -90
2. switch to 'Edit Mode' from object mode
3. select all the mesh by press <kbd>A</kbd>
4. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > cursor to world origin
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > Selection to curson (keep offset)
   I tried to convert the GUI opreation to python command, like follow:

```
import bpy

import math

obj = bpy.data.objects.get("halfface")

obj.rotation_euler[0] += math.radians(-90)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj.select_set(True)

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='BOUNDS')

obj.location = (0, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

But it gave me an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\SomeData\testdata\skullblend\skull.py", line 36, in <module>
    bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=True)
  File "D:\OtherSoftware\blender\4.0\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 109, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor.poll() failed, context is incorrect`
```

And the last step "selection to cursor (keep offset)" not work.

Can anyone gave me some advice ? I really confused about the context
Really appreciate for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator needs a View 3D context.

```py
import bpy

import math

import typing

def call_with_override(override: typing.Dict[str, typing.Any], func: typing.Callable, *args, **kwargs):

    if bpy.app.version > (3, 2, 0):
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        result = func(override, *args, **kwargs)

    if 'CANCELLED' in result:
        raise Exception(f"The operator has been cancelled: {repr(func)}")

    return result


def get_view3d():
    for window_manager in bpy.data.window_managers:
        for window in window_manager.windows:
            for area in window.screen.areas:
                if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                    for region in area.regions:
                        if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                            return dict(window=window, workspace=window.workspace, screen=window.screen, area=area, region=region)

    raise Exception('View3D context not found.')


def call_in_view3d(func: typing.Callable, *args, **kwargs):
    return call_with_override(get_view3d(), func, *args, **kwargs)


obj = bpy.data.objects[0]

obj.rotation_euler[0] += math.radians(-90)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

obj.select_set(True)

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)

bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type='ORIGIN_CURSOR', center='BOUNDS')

obj.location = (0, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')

call_in_view3d(bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor, use_offset=True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Although in this case you should consider a lower level API approach by moving the vertices themselves, some `bpy.ops` operators are much easier to utilize or have no alternatives.